# How to interact with VBA objects in sheets using xlwings?

Tags: python, excel, vba, xlwings

I'm trying to write a programmatic way to run through the CCIO 2016 Actuarial Value calculator ([download](https://www.cms.gov/CCIIO/Resources/Regulations-and-Guidance/Downloads/Draft-2016-AV-Calculator.xlsm)) using `xlwings`. What I'd like to be able to do is interact with the checkboxes present in the different columns so I can vary the designs. My question is: how do I extract those as objects that can be interacted with?

I am not married to `xlwings`, so I'd be happy with either an `xlwings` or non-`xlwings` solution.

- System: Mac
- Python: 2.7
- xlwings: 0.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This runs under the category "Missing Features" which is documented [here](http://docs.xlwings.org/missing_features.html).

Since the workaround-syntax of the underlying appscript package (on Mac) is not really straight forward, here an example to get you started:

```
>>> import xlwings as xw

>>> wb = xw.Workbook('WorkbookName')
>>> xw.Sheet('SheetName').xl_sheet.checkboxes['CheckBox_Name'].value.get()
k.checkbox_off
```